# Can nginx run a unix command based on url?

Tags: url, configuration, nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx to run a unix command based on a url?

For example:

```
http://localhost/list/usr/local
```

This runs:

```
ls /usr/local
```

Then returns the results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Nginx cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx is able to run perl scripts when it's built with perl support. And it seems that you can program enything that can be done with a plain perl.

I think you should look at this direction.

While expirementing with perl you should keep in mind that perl interpreter blocks nginx process until finished so it's not recomended to run long-lasting jobs.

BTW: Perl support still marked as experimental.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perl module for this task.

[Nginx Perl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html)